# como con un boton precargar en una caja de texto un texto y con el mismo boton generar la busqueda en html-php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html5

El problema es el siguiente, como con un boton precargar en una caja de texto un texto y con el mismo boton generar la busqueda en html-php-mysql.
Intente varias opciones logro enviar el "POST" pero en vacio no logro cargar el texto de ingles en la caja de texto con el boton-Ingles no logro resolverlo, aca les dejo un corto del codigo espero me puedan ayudar saludos y gracias.

```
<form method="POST" action="" onSubmit="return validarForm(this)">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre-Apellido-Idioma" name="palabra" style="height:30px; width:260px" autofocus>

      <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">

         <div>


    <br><br><h3>Busquelo por idioma</h3>
    <input type="submit" class="" name="buscar" value="Inglés" style="height:30px; width:95px" />
    <input type="submit" class="" name="buscar" value="Italiano" style="height:30px; width:95px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO a este problema, estaba por buen camino pero necesitaba corregir algunos detalles para que funciones les pongo la solucion y como logre solucionarlo saludos espero les ayude este pequeño codigo.

```
<form method="POST" action="" onSubmit="return validarForm(this)" name="f1" id="f1">

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre-Apellido-Idioma" name="palabra" id="palabra" autofocus>

                            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">

                                <div>


                                <br><br><h3>Busquelo por idioma</h3>
                                //aca el boton para envio y ejecute el codigo para rellenar la caja de texto
                                <input type="submit" class="" name="buscar" value="Inglés" onclick="ingles(ingles)"/>

                                </div>
                        </form>
                       //aca el pequeño codigo para llenar la caja de texto
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function ingles(ingles){
                                        a="ingles";
                                    document.f1.palabra.value=a; 
                                        }
                                </script>
```